# how to use std in code without including "using namespace std"?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, std

**In this code of operator Overloading, i don't want to write "using namespace std" instead i want to include "std::" wherever required.**

After adding "std::" after cout and cin, i am still getting Errors where else to include "std::".

```
#include<iostream>
//using namespace std;
class Complex
{
private:
  int real, imag;
public:
  Complex(int r = 0, int i = 0) : real(r), imag(i) {}

  friend ostream & operator << (ostream &, const Complex &);
  friend istream & operator >> (istream &, Complex &);
};

ostream & operator << (ostream &out, Complex &obj)
{
  out<<obj.real<<" "<<obj.imag;
  return out;
}
istream & operator >> (istream &in, const Complex &obj)
{
  in>>obj.real>>obj.imag;
  return in;
}

int main()
{
  Complex obj;
  std::cin>>obj;
  std::cout<<obj;
  return 0;
}
```

It should take input two numbers using istream operator and output two numbers using ostream operator.

Comment: what errors do you get?

Comment: what namespace are `ostream` and `istream` from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add `std::` to `ostream` and `istream`

They come from the headers [`<istream>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/istream) and [`<ostream>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/ostream) and are defined in `<iosfwd>`

```
#include<iostream>
//using namespace std;
class Complex
{
private:
    int real, imag;
public:

    Complex(int r = 0, int i = 0) : real(r), imag(i) {}

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Complex& obj);
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, Complex& obj);
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Complex &obj)
{
    out << obj.real << " " << obj.imag;
    return out;
}
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream &in, Complex &obj)
{
    in >> obj.real >> obj.imag;
    return in;
}

int main()
{
    Complex obj;
    std::cin >> obj;
    std::cout << obj;
    return 0;
}
```

---

(not related to the `std::` problem) 
You can also  access your private variables outside the class without the `friend` declaration by using get/set member functions. Thanks to @aschepler for pointing out my mistake regarding the accessibility.

```
#include<iostream>
class Complex
{
private:
    int real, imag;
public:
    int get_real() const {
        return real;
    }
    void set_real(int real) {
        this->real = real;
    }
    int get_imag() const {
        return imag;
    }
    void set_imag(int imag) {
        this->imag = imag;
    }

    Complex(int r = 0, int i = 0) : real(r), imag(i) {}

};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Complex &obj)
{
    out << obj.get_real() << " " << obj.get_real();
    return out;
}
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream &in, Complex &obj)
{
    int real, imag;
    in >> real >> imag;
    obj.set_real(real);
    obj.set_imag(imag);
    return in;
}

int main()
{
    Complex obj;
    std::cin >> obj;
    std::cout << obj;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The STL didn't use namespaces, as far as I can recall.

Comment: But when i was using "namespace std" it was working, why now i have to write a get_real() and get_imag() functions? Can you tell me more about it.

Comment: The `friend` declarations allow access to the private members. Those functions might be good for other code that wants to get the real or imaginary components of a complex number, but they're not necessary in the program shown.

Comment: @AdityaIshan i posted the edited code, take a look at it.

Comment: @StackDanny Thanks a lot :). Learnt new concepts today.

Comment: @AdityaIshan note the commend by aschepler. This answer is slightly misleading, actually strictly speaking it is wrong, you can access private members in friends

Comment: yes @AdityaIshan, they are right, I overlooked the `friend` declarations. I edited it again. Sorry for missing it out. Well, now you've seen both possible way on how to hande private variables.

Comment: @StackDanny Yes, i was going to comment about that only, but anyways thanks to everyone for their effort.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit  True, the original versions of the STL did not use namespaces.   However, a number of vendors produced their own incantation of STL, and some of the more recent ones did use namespaces.   STLPort was one which used a namespace named `_STL::`.   Apache produced a library that was labelled as STL, openly derived from a STL version donated to Apache by RogueWave in 2005, and (presumably due to awareness of C++ standards) used namespace `std`.   That product was discontinued in 2014.

Comment: @Peter Sad that an implementation of something other than the standard library would use `std` :(

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - depends on perspective.   I remember seeing a vision described for that product to become a standard-compliant library that could be licensed to compiler vendors.   That never came to be, possibly because most compiler vendors decided to implement their own.

Comment: @StackDanny One last question, which one is the best practise to write for the two solutions you gave?

Comment: @Peter That would have been better :)

Comment: @AdityaIshan I prefere the second version. so, no `friend`. If you really want to overload these operators for a class where there can't have a get/set function (because the data has to be unmodifiable), well than you *have* to use `friend`. But that rarely happens. And if it does, you can always still provide a public `std::string to_string() const` function for the `<<` operator to call. Since I never use the `>>` operator this small workaround always works for me (and the data is private!)

Answer (score 0):

Your favourite standard library reference tells you what namespace things are in. In a tiny program like this, you can simply look up each one in turn.

Hint: they're all in `std`.

So that includes `std::ostream` and `std::istream`.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a *namespace pollution problem*. The importance of it may vary between usages.

When you are just prototyping, `using namespace std;` is fine, as is including useless headers just in case you need something from one. When you want a super safe code that will be extensively reviewed, you want to prevent name collision and namespace pollutino, so you include in the current namespace only what is required, and you give explicit namepaces for idendifiers that are only seldom used.

The following is more of my own opinion (or more exactly the way I am used to work):

- when a symbol is seldom used, I give it its explicit namespace (eg: `std::cout << i;`)
- when a symbol is heavily used in a compilation unit, I import specifically that symbol (eg: `using std::cout; ... cout << i; ... cout << j; ...`)